# How to trace an Error: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]:

Tags: debugging

I'm trying to trace this error which is shown when I save a new **basic page** node.

It seems to me that I am trying to save a duplicated title value in **field_data_title_field**, but it doesn't make any sense to me. I found this question [PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1532856' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {watchdog}](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/158953/pdoexception-sqlstate23000-integrity-constraint-violation-1062-duplicate-en) but it was related to dblog table (Watchdog module). Mine is related to: **modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module**

Drupal core is updated to last version.

How can I trace and fix this?

ERROR:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'node-4294967295-0-0-und' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {field_data_title_field} (entity_type, entity_id, revision_id, bundle, delta, language, title_field_value, title_field_format) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5, :db_insert_placeholder_6, :db_insert_placeholder_7); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 4294967295 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 3187 [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => page [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => und [:db_insert_placeholder_6] => My node title [:db_insert_placeholder_7] => ) enfield_sql_storage_field_storage_write() (line 514 of /home/examplesite/www/modules/field/modules/field_sql_storage/field_sql_storage.module )

Answer (score 1):

The composite primary key for field tables is `entity_type`,`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`language`. The error itself lists the key:

```
'node-4294967295-0-0-und'
```

You can confirm that there is a pre-existing field in the table by querying your database with a search on those values.

Also of note, your node id is at 4294967295. This is the upper limit of 32-bit unsigned integers; anything higher than that is going to start causing problems with your SQL storage.

Comment: Then I understand that the problem is the field reached it limit. And the problem is not a "duplicated" value. Am I right?

Comment: Without access to the DB I can't say for certain, but it does look like the duplicate entry is a side effect of your node id sequence being maxed out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've reached your limit for your data value in this column, the value is acting as a MAX and using the maximum value that can be stored in the column. In this case, it's already in use.